# Running Swift script with Cocoapods dependency

Tags: swift, cocoa, scripting, dependencies, cocoapods

I have an iOS project using Cocoapods. One of the pods I use is https://github.com/mattrubin/OneTimePassword. I wrote a little wrapper that wraps the functionality of this pod -- in my case, it's to print out the password at the current time. This all works fine.

I want to write a script in Swift that basically does the printing from the command line. I followed the tutorial here https://krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift but when I try compiling my script, the compiler doesn't think my framework is available..

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

// import OneTimePassword // This is the Pod I'm trying to use. I get the error: error: no such module 'OneTimePassword'

print(MyWrapperClass.shared.printPwd()) // error: use of unresolved identifier 'MyWrapperClass'
```

I'm compiling with the command `swiftc main.swift -o main`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. This page is a top result for searching "swift scripting cocoapods", but it still being unanswered makes me think not too many people are trying to use swift for scripting yet.

> First of all, if you're compiling your code then it's not really a script, just a tiny program. The point of the "#!" line in a script is so you can mark it as executable (yes the source file, with `chmod a+x blah.swift`), put it in a executable path like /usr/local/bin, type `blah.swift` in your shell. The swift compiler knows to build then run it for you (yes, rebuilds it every time because swift is not an interpreter, but its not unreasonable to do this for tiny code). It's ok to omit the file extension from your swift file if you want the command you type to be just "blah".

Sadly, it looks like there's nothing quite like perl's CPAN that can add a swift packages to your system and allow it to be used in simple executable swift scripts. The Swift Package Manager and cocoapods-rome both assume your script has a project source directory, kind of assuming one was going to build it then install the binary (though that's seems to be kinda what you expecting to do anyway). **EDIT: I was wrong, the thing mentioned in the following paragraph will do this after all.**

What I found that's pretty close is "marathon" https://github.com/johnsundell/marathon, which makes it easy to create, run, debug scripts with dependencies without exposing a directory of its source & crap. Unfortunately you lose the simplicity of your script being a file you mark as executable and run by name, your script file is hidden in some *managed place* and executed by way of the `marathon run blah` command. However, shell aliases/functions can hide that messy business for you, and that's what I plan to do.

The author of marathon also has a collection of links to tools & packages for scripting in swift: https://github.com/JohnSundell/SwiftScripting

**EDIT:** It looks like the special shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env marathon run` will let one use bare scripts with marathon-installed pods/packages after all. If you want to make use of this, 7ball, then do this:

- install marathon (hmm, homebrew version is stale, follow the Swift Package Manager instructions instead)
- change the shebang line in your script from `#!/usr/bin/swift` to the above
- uncomment your "import" line and add the special marathon comment after it like this: `import OneTimePassword // marathon:https://github.com/mattrubin/OneTimePassword.git`
- (or install it into marathon ahead of time using `marathon add https://github.com/mattrubin/OneTimePassword.git` and don't put that funny comment on your "import" line)
- run with "./main.swift"